# SQL query - filter with cascading conditions

Tags: sql

I've two tables T1 and T2 with the following columns -

T1

```
Project_ID
Category
Column_X
Column_Y
Column_Z
```

T2

```
Proj_ID
Category
Parent_Project_ID
```

I want to write a query to get records from T1 with the following condition -

1. Get Projects with Category = "A" from T1
2. Get child projects of the above filtered projects

I'm not sure how to check the second condition only with the results coming out of first condition.

**What is needed?**

1. Projects from T1 where Category is A
2. Child projects of projects obtained from condition 1

Adding sample data and desired results as requested -

[image: Sample data and results]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "join"?  It is a basic building block of SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was about to do it. Yes I know joins. But I believe join will not help me here if you can understand my question.

Comment: This is a really bad table structure for this...  But yes, `Join` will help you.

Comment: I know. I hate this structure. But can you help how to use join here? I'm not an expert in SQL but I understand basic inner and outer (left and right) joins.

Comment: @NVL . . . We think we understand your question.  You should provide sample data and desired results to remove as much ambiguity as possible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry for not adding sample data and expected results. I've added it now. Please check it. In joins can we do something like this?

Comment: I would really like to know why the question is being downvoted. I can try to update the question with more details if it is not clear.

Comment: @NLV . . . The question doesn't seem to deserve a downvote.  It is preferred to put actual values in the question rather than images, but that it a minor thing (except for code, because responders would like to copy the code for their own answers).  Downvotes on questions have become much more prevalent since Stack Overflow changed the rules and the downvoter on a question no longer gets nicked a point.

Answer (score 2):

To get all records from second table then you can use the following query.

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM    T1 t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN T2 t2 ON t1.Project_ID = t2.Project_ID
WHERE t1.Category = "A"
```

Comment: Kindly check the sample data and sample results. I want projects with category = 'A' from T1. And then I want its child projects from T2.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE T2.Proj_ID IN ( SELECT Project_ID FROM T1 WHERE Category = 'A' )
```

This should do the job needed.

```
SELECT * from T2  as d 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * from T1 as d1 where d1.Category  = 'A' and d1.Project_ID = d.Proj_ID ) 


 SELECT * from T1 as d1 right join T2  as d2 on d1.Project_ID = d2.Proj_ID 
WHERE d1.CodTert = 500
```

I've made an update, these query give the same result, one uses the JOIN one doesn't.

Comment: I need column_x, column_y, column_z from T1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `T2`.`Parent_Project_ID` and `T1`.`Project_ID` are related.  If so, you can use this:

```
Select  T3.*
From    T1  
Join    T2      On  T2.Parent_Project_ID = T1.Project_ID
Join    T1  T3  On  T3.Project_ID = T2.Proj_ID  
Where   T1.Category = 'A'
```

This would get only child projects of projects that have a category of 'A'.

Comment: I want only child projects of the Projects from T1 where Category = 'A'. Where is it included in your query?

Comment: You would need to `Join` back to the original table `T1` for that.  I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Multiple joins is the solution. Let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
Based on the output format that has been added to the question, the following query, which uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would render the exact result required:

```
SELECT
    T2.PROJ_ID Project_ID,
    T2.Category,
    T1.Column_X,
    T1.Column_Y,
    T1.Column_Z,
    T2.Parent_Project_ID
FROM T1 T1_PARENTS
INNER JOIN T2
ON T2.Parent_Project_ID = T1.Project_ID and T1.Category = 'A'
INNER JOIN T2 T2_CHILDREN
ON T2_CHILDREN.PROJ_ID = T2.Parent_Project_ID OR T2_CHILDREN.Parent_Project_ID = T2.Parent_Project_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1
ON T2_CHILDREN.PROJ_ID = T1.Project_ID;
```

Comment: I still don't understand how only the child projects of projects selected from T1 are pulled. Aren't we suppose to have a condition like T1.Project_ID = T2.Parent_Project_ID?

Comment: Please see the modified query under the EDIT section.

Comment: Yes. I checked the edit section. I don't see any conditions for category and the parent-child relation of the projects.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. You want to limit the parent project ID's to only those with Category A. I'll update the query.

Comment: Please see updated query above. First, the parent project id's for Category A are selected. Then, their children as well as the parents are selected from T2. The Column X, Column Y, and Column Z values are selected from T1 if they are available (for parents).